# Move text input before tags in bootstrap-tagsinput

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-tags-input

Is there an easy way to move the text input above the tags in bootstrap-tagsinput?

Here's a codepen that might illustrate what I mean: https://codepen.io/uebes/pen/KQEdeP

In other words, I want tags to prepend AFTER my input text box like this:

```
    <div class="bootstrap-tagsinput">
        <input type="text" placeholder="">
        <span class="tag label label-info"> Test 1<span data-role="remove"></span></span>
        <span class="tag label label-info"> Test 2<span data-role="remove"></span></span>
        <span class="tag label label-info"> Test 3<span data-role="remove"></span></span>
        <span class="tag label label-info"> Test 4<span data-role="remove"></span></span>
        <span class="tag label label-info"> Test 5<span data-role="remove"></span></span>
    </div>
```

Rather than the default, in which new tags are added right before the text box:

```
    <div class="bootstrap-tagsinput">
        <span class="tag label label-info"> Test 1<span data-role="remove"></span></span>
        <span class="tag label label-info"> Test 2<span data-role="remove"></span></span>
        <span class="tag label label-info"> Test 3<span data-role="remove"></span></span>
        <span class="tag label label-info"> Test 4<span data-role="remove"></span></span>
        <span class="tag label label-info"> Test 5<span data-role="remove"></span></span>
        <input type="text" placeholder="">
    </div>
```

Comment: you need to explain the question in better way so any one may answer you... this question does not make sense.

Comment: Sorry @AneesIjaz ! What I mean is, is it possible to have the tags follow the <input> rather than precede it? From what I can find, the text input box is always after the tags, I'd like the tags to prepend after the input. Sorry if I'm still not clear, I'm new to bootstrap-tagsinput.js.

Here's a link to a codepen that might help communicate what I'm struggling with:
https://codepen.io/uebes/pen/KQEdeP

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean this...?

```html
<div class="bootstrap-tagsinput">
        <input type="text" placeholder=""><br>
        <span class="tag label label-info"> Test 1<span data-role="remove"></span></span>
        <span class="tag label label-info"> Test 2<span data-role="remove"></span></span>
        <span class="tag label label-info"> Test 3<span data-role="remove"></span></span>
        <span class="tag label label-info"> Test 4<span data-role="remove"></span></span>
        <span class="tag label label-info"> Test 5<span data-role="remove"></span></span>
    </div>
```

Comment: Not exactly. To be clear, the markup I included in my question is generated by bootstrap-tagsinput.js.

The way I'm doing it, I add `data-role="tagsinput"` to my input tag. I'm wondering if there's an easy way to have the tags prepend rather than append?

Here's a link to a codepen that might explain what I mean better:[https://codepen.io/uebes/pen/KQEdeP]